# React-DatePicker - how to disable closing on start date selection

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-datepicker

I develop DatePicker for components library, and using the `react-datepicker` npm to do so.

The desired behavior is that the user click the input, the date picker will open, the user will select 2 dates, when click on the 2nd date the DatePicker will close.

The issue is that the picker is being closed on the start date selection.

I removed all my code, and use the exact example displayed in the npm demo:

[https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-date-range-using-input-with-clear-button](http://npm%20demo)

still the date picker is closing on the start date select.

I tried adding `shouldCloseOnSelect` set to `true` but then it doesn't close on end date select as well.

how to prevent the closing on the start date, and allow it on the end date.

**current code:**

```
const MyDatePicker = () => {
  const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState([null, null]);
  const [testStart, testEnd] = dateRange;
  return (
    <ReactDatePicker
      selectsRange={true}
      startDate={testStart}
      endDate={testEnd}
      onChange={(update: any) => {
        setDateRange(update);
      }}
      isClearable={true}
    />
  );

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known issue - [Github issue](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/issues/2959)

I work around it using `open`, `onInputClick`  and `onClickOutside` props, like this:

```
const MyDatePicker = () => {
 const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <ReactDatePicker
      onInputClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}
      onClickOutside={() => setIsOpen(false)}
      open={isOpen}
      selectsRange={true}
      startDate={testStart}
      endDate={testEnd}
      onChange={(update: any) => {
        setDateRange(update);
        if (update[1]) {
          setIsOpen(false);
        }
      }}
      isClearable={true}
    />
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shouldCloseOnSelect` prop:

```
const MyDatePicker = () => {
    const [dateRange, setDateRange] = useState([null, null]);
    const [startDate, endDate] = dateRange;

    return (
        <ReactDatePicker
            selectsRange={true}
            shouldCloseOnSelect={!(!startDate || Boolean(startDate && endDate))}
            startDate={startDate}
            endDate={endDate}
            onChange={(update: any) => {
                setDateRange(update);
            }}
            isClearable={true}
        />
    );

}
```