# react-datepicker, How to expose both startDate and endDate on a button using format

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-datepicker

How to expose both startDate and endDate on a button using format.

```
<>
      <button className="example-custom-input" onClick={handleClick}>
        {format(startDate, "dd-MM-yyyy")}
      </button>
      {isOpen && (
        <DatePicker selected={startDate} onChange={handleChange} inline />
      )}
    </>
```

```
<button className="example-custom-input" onClick={handleClick}>
  {format(startDate + endDate, "MM dd")} 
</button>
```

`start:'MM dd' ~ end:'MM dd'`

`'MM dd ~ MM dd'`

Comment: See the react-datepicker docs for an example of how to do exactly this: https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-date-range-for-one-datepicker

Comment: Im Using 'Button to show Inline version'

Comment: Use `{format(startDate, "dd-MM-yyyy") + ' ~ ' + format(endDate, "dd-MM-yyyy") }` to expose both dates.

Comment: It works once with the code you provided. From the second select, 'Invalid time value' error is called.

Comment: You can use the `shouldCloseOnSelect={!(!startDate || Boolean(startDate && endDate))}` prop on your DatePicker. See this thread for further discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67700522/react-datepicker-how-to-disable-closing-on-start-date-selection?rq=1